# Openshift for Play: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Tags: ssh, playframework-2.0, openshift, typesafe-activator

I am trying to launch a play project in openshift. The first phase which was nearly 15% of the project was successfully completed and uploaded. So, I guess the initial configuration was okay. Now, after I completed nearly the rest of the project, then when I am trying to push the project using ssh, everytime after a certain time the remote server hangs up with the following message.

```
remote: [info] Done packaging.
remote: model contains 69 documentable templates
Connection to blogofprime-thatsqt.rhcloud.com closed by remote host.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
error: error in sideband demultiplexer
To ssh://5455ef32e0b8cd379e000293@blogofprime-thatsqt.rhcloud.com/~/git/blogofprime.git/
 + 557ec12...4034b71 HEAD -> master (forced update)
```

Every-time after a certain step remote server hangs up.

My openshift.conf file:

```
# This is the main configuration file for the application.
# ~~~~~

include "application"

# Secret key
# ~~~~~
# The secret key is used to secure cryptographics functions.
# If you deploy your application to several instances be sure to use the same key!
application.secret="V0sLX<RAciXw_>7^O8y=I4BRW/M4@vhVhF=H44`lMfgAV2hs^Pp?tsfroKt1J3eX"

# The application languages
# ~~~~~
application.langs="en"

# Database configuration
# ~~~~~ 
# You can declare as many datasources as you want.
# By convention, the default datasource is named `default`
#

db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://"${OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST}":"${OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT}"/"${OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME}
db.default.user=${OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME}
db.default.password=${OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD}

# Evolutions
# ~~~~~
# You can disable evolutions if needed
# evolutionplugin=disabled

# Ebean configuration
# ~~~~~
# You can declare as many Ebean servers as you want.
# By convention, the default server is named `default`
#
ebean.default="models.*"


# Logger
# ~~~~~
# You can also configure logback (http://logback.qos.ch/), by providing a logger.xml file in the conf directory .

# Root logger:
logger.root=ERROR

# Logger used by the framework:
logger.play=INFO

# Logger provided to your application:
logger.application=DEBUG
```

My build.sbt file:

```
name := "thatsqt"

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

scalaVersion := "2.11.2" // or "2.10.4"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  // Select Play modules
  jdbc,      // The JDBC connection pool and the play.api.db API
  //anorm,     // Scala RDBMS Library
  javaJdbc,  // Java database API
  javaEbean, // Java Ebean plugin
  javaJpa,   // Java JPA plugin
  filters,   // A set of built-in filters
  javaCore,  // The core Java API
  // WebJars pull in client-side web librarie
  "org.webjars" %% "webjars-play" % "2.3.0",
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick" % "0.8.0",
  // Add your own project dependencies in the form:
  // "group" % "artifact" % "version"
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.27"
)

fork in Test := false

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)

EclipseKeys.withSource := true
```

Platform:
I am using Mac OS X and typesafe activator for play framework.

What I tried:
I tried to `unset TMOUT` in both server and client. At this point I am not very sure whether this is a timeout problem or something else.

My project Link: https://github.com/magurmach/PlayOpenshiftThatsQt

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: This happens when the gear RAM quota is exceeded; though I am not saying this is necessarily the cause.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem started occurring recently, it may be caused by exceeded quota.
It's very common to run out of space using 1GB small gears.

Try using rhc app-tidy rhc command:

```
rhc app-tidy <app>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does your project include large binary files? This can cause git to take up a lot of RAM server-side, and a small Openshift gear will kill things that take too much RAM.  The solution is to ssh into your Openshift box (using "rhc ssh" or equivalent) and tell the server-side git to limit its RAM use:

```
cd git/*.git
git config pack.windowMemory "25m"
git config pack.packSizeLimit "25m"
git config pack.threads "1"
```

and why they didn't do that by default I have no idea.

Also, next time you want to put large binary files into your project, you don't *have* to check them into the git repository (which will take up space tracking their entire history): you *could* just instruct your app to download them from another server as needed (the second server needs only the ability to host static files).